# Resizing Choropleth map using Plotly-Dash on Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm having trouble scaling my plotly.graph_objects Choropleth along with it's container. I read through the documentation for the class but I couldn't find anything related to scaling the graph. Is there some way for me to make the graph fill up more of the container as well as making the container taller?

```
fig = px.choropleth(country_df, geojson = world_countries, locations = 'iso_alpha',
featureidkey= 'id', color = "Killed", color_continuous_scale ="ice", range_color = (0,1500),
labels = {'Country': 'Killed'}, hover_name= 'Country')
fig.update_layout( margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, paper_bgcolor = 'black', autosize = True)
fig.update_geos(projection_scale = 1.65,)
```

Image of Graph
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7rzy.png

Comment: You can try modifying it to `autosize=False` and specify the desired graph size. However, it will be affected by the display size of your browser.